# How to get ip of client on server?

Tags: java, ipv4

I am looking for a way to get the ip address of client request on the server side.
By the way its not servlet project.

Comment: I am trying to work out what you are asking here.  You say that you want to get the client address using `HttpURLConnection`.  But that is a **client side** library.  So why would you want to get the client IP on the client side?

Comment: You must identify your server-side technology. Not just tell us what it *isn't.*

Answer (score 2):

- Server getting IP of client: [`Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress--)
- Client getting IP of server: you already have it.
- Client/Server getting own IP address: make a request to a site that gives you that info:

  ```
  URLConnection conn = new URL("http://ifconfig.co/ip").openConnection();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
  int b;
  while((b=stream.read())!=-1) {
      sb.append((char)b);
  }
  stream.close();
  String ip = sb.toString();
  ```

Comment: Server getting ip of client is what i wanted, is it possible to get the host name of client?

Comment: `Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1",9200);
    String sock_addr = client.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
    String ip_addr = client.getInetAddress().toString()`   i tried this code but it returns 127.0.0.1:9200, but i want ip address

Comment: @Radha That's just a way for the client to get its own IP address, which (a) it already supplied to itself as 127.0.0.1 and (b) it doesn't need. Please clarify, again, whether you want (1) the server to get its own IP address; (2) the server to get the client's IP address; (3) the client to get its own IP address; or (4) the client get the server's IP address. Note that (1) is unnecessary; (2) has been answered; (3) is pointless; and (4) doesn't make sense, as the client can't *be* connected to the server unless it already knows that.